# <v-select> validate if some information was selected

Tags: vuetify.js

Personal,

I'm using Vuetify v-select, when a button is clicked check if v-select was selected if it doesn't show an alert to the user that he needs to select some data in v-select?
I am not able to do these checks.

```
<v-select
          dense
          label="Local de Estoque"
          outlined
          :items="LocalEstoques"
          item-text="descricao"
          item-value="id"
          v-model="group"
          clearable
          requerid        
></v-select>


validaSelect() {

    if (this.group.descricao){     //Here I can not validate null ou empty
     alert("erro");
    }

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vuetify's `rules` prop to set rules to an input.
You can use the `v-form` to validate all inputs in a form and to check if the current state is valid

I've created an example for you:

https://codepen.io/ricardovanlaarhoven/pen/eYydePZ

just do whatever you like instead of the two alerts